# What does code guru java/inconsistent-or-missing-api@v1.0 mean?

Tags: java, aws-codeguru

Code guru throws this error:

Issue: We found 4 occurrences in your code of a similar method that calls ErrorCode.name. Based on those occurrences, we expect it to be called after the selected line. We recommend you check if this is intentional. The following is an example in your code of when this method is called:service-core/src/main/java/com/my/path/SomeClass.java#L61

Severity: Critical

Rule ID: java/inconsistent-or-missing-api@v1.0

Rule Name: Inconsistent or missing API

Description: An inconsistent or missing API call could cause unexpected errors. We recommend that you handle API calls consistently to help ensure they are used properly.

ErrorCode is an enum.
How can this be fixed? And what does it mean?

Comment: Well, it's not just you. That description is terrible. :)

Comment: Could not agree more. Poor description, no examples, but it is a critical issue :D 
How are we supposed to fix that?